# How magento decides order of all _module.less file imported through @magento_import directive?

Tags: magento2, less, grunt, less-compilation

I am trying to add module specific less file named _module.less inside my custom module **Mynamespace_Mymodule** in M2.

For that I have created module.xml file with below sequence.

```
<module name="Mynamespace_Mymodule" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales" />
            <module name="Magento_Payment" />
            <module name="Magento_Checkout" />
        </sequence>
</module>
```

and thus corresponding sequence is generated inside `app/etc/config.php` file.

However the sequence for my **_module.less** file is not the same as the order of module I set from module.xml. Instead, my **_module.less** file comes before those two modules that I set inside sequence, so I have to use ugly **!important** flag every time inside less file to override css properties.

Here is how compiled order for **_module.less** is inside `styles-m.less` after `grunt exec:theme` command.

```
@import '../Mynamespace_Mymodule/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Checkout/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Sales/css/source/_module.less';
```

How magento decides order for _module.less file?